# Why doesn't diffusion models suffer posterior collapse?

Tags: generative-model, variational-autoencoder, diffusion-models

In VAEs, posterior collapse occurs when the approximated posterior $q_\theta(z|x)$ becomes the standard Gaussian prior after training. The forward process of diffusion models transforms the data $x$ into a standard Gaussian at time step $T$, which is similar to approximating the posterior $p(z|x)$ in hierarchical VAEs (see this [blog](https://jmtomczak.github.io/blog/10/10_ddgms_lvm_p2.html) for more details). Therefore, I am wondering whether diffusion models suffer from the issue of posterior collapse, if that makes sense at all.